# How to plot multiple timelines in one graph?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, gantt-chart

I have two different Dataframes containing various columns : start & end date, Duration ...

I would like to plot the data into Timelines(Gantt charts) using plotly express. I know how to use subplots however I want them on the same graphic not figure.

#### Here is my attempt :

'''

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.timeline(chosen_data3, x_start="Start Date", x_end="End Date", y="new" )
fig2 = px.timeline(chosen_data4, x_start="Start Date", x_end="End Date", y="new", ax = fig )
fig2.show()

#Using graph_objs :

fig = go.Figure()

for (start, end, value, value2) in zip(chosen_data3["Start Date"], chosen_data3["End Date"], 
chosen_data3["Duration [Hours]"],chosen_data3["Hs [m]"] ):
   name = f"Towing : {start} to {end}"
   fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[start, end], y=[value, value],mode='lines', name = name , marker = 
   dict(color = 'rgb(0,0,0)'), hoverinfo = 'all'))    

 for (start, end, value, value2) in zip(chosen_data4["Start Date"], chosen_data4["End Date"], chosen_data4["Duration [Hours]"], chosen_data4["Hs [m]"]):
name = f"Hook-Up :{start} to {end}"
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[start, end], y=[value, value],mode='lines', name = name, marker = dict(color = 'rgb(65,105,225)'), hoverinfo = 'all')) 

fig.show()
```

'''

The solution with graph_objs is correct however the one using express didn't

EDIT :
Sample of my two dataframes :

[image]

Solution using Graph objs :

[image]

The solution I tried was to concatenate the two dataframes & create a new column to differentiate each data, I get the following figure using plotly express timeline when you hover over each bar you see all the information needed :

[image]

Comment: Was I ambiguous or unclear ? I can reformulate in that case ...

Comment: Can you include a sample of your DataFrame, and also include an image of your solution using graph_objects? This will help people answer your question because the way you have written it right now, it's not reproducible.

Comment: There you go, I hope it's clearer

Comment: Yeah, much clearer! Hopefully someone can help answer your question, I'll take a look a bit later when I have a moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right idea: to reproduce the figure you made with plotly graph_objects using plotly express, we need to create new columns for your two DataFrames to hold information that you'll need to pass to the `px.timeline` method. Then we can concatenate the two DataFrames and pass the one combined DataFrame to px.timeline.

We can create a column called `legend_entry` to hold the string that you want to be displayed in the legend, and pass this to the `color` parameter of px.timeline. However since the color parameter is also used to assign colors to the bars, and each legend_entry you have will be unique, each bar will be a different color — we can override this by passing an explicit array of colors to be assigned to each bar to the parameter `color_discrete_sequence`. To do this, we can create an additional column called `color` that we will populate with `'black'` or `'blue'` depending on towing or hook-up tasks.

Since the topmost and bottommost bars will be right up against the edge of the plot, we can add some padding by expanding the range of the y-axis by however many hours you like. I chose 10.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

## recreate your data
chosen_data3 = pd.DataFrame({
    "Start Date":['1999-03-06 05:00:00','1999-03-08 22:00:00','1999-03-12 22:00:00','1999-03-22 19:00:00'],
    "End Date":['1999-03-08 00:00:00','1999-03-12 19:00:00','1999-03-21 20:00:00','1999-03-26 03:00:00'],
    "Hs [m]":[1.804182,1.461362,1.825023,1.717531]
})

chosen_data4 = pd.DataFrame({
    "Start Date":['1999-03-09 06:00:00','1999-03-20 05:00:00'],
    "End Date":['1999-03-11 18:00:00','1999-03-21 10:00:00'],
    "Hs [m]":[1.209672,1.121267]
})

chosen_data3[['Start Date','End Date']] = chosen_data3[['Start Date','End Date']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
chosen_data4[['Start Date','End Date']] = chosen_data4[['Start Date','End Date']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

chosen_data3['Duration [Hours]'] = (chosen_data3['End Date'] - chosen_data3['Start Date']) / np.timedelta64(1, 'h')
chosen_data4['Duration [Hours]'] = (chosen_data4['End Date'] - chosen_data4['Start Date']) / np.timedelta64(1, 'h')

## add a new column with a string for the legend
chosen_data3['legend_entry'] = "Towing : " + chosen_data3['Start Date'].apply(str) + " to " + chosen_data3['End Date'].apply(str) 
chosen_data4['legend_entry'] = "Hook up : " + chosen_data4['Start Date'].apply(str) + " to " + chosen_data4['End Date'].apply(str)

## add a new column to specify the color of each bar
chosen_data3['color'] = 'black'
chosen_data4['color'] = 'blue'

## we can concatenate the data into one DataFrame so that we only need to use px.timeline once
df = pd.concat([chosen_data3, chosen_data4])

## pass an explicit array to the color_discrete_sequence 
fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start Date", x_end="End Date", y="Duration [Hours]", 
    color="legend_entry", color_discrete_sequence=df.color.values)

## add some padding so that the bottom and topmost bars aren't flush against the edge of the figure
y_axis_range_padding = 10
fig.update_layout(
    title="Towing & Hook up tasks in function of duration", title_x=0.5, 
    legend_title_text='', yaxis_range=[df['Duration [Hours]'].min() - y_axis_range_padding, df['Duration [Hours]'].max() + y_axis_range_padding]
    )
fig.show()
```

[image]